# CakePhp, How do i add to check if the uploaded file is image only?

Tags: php, validation, cakephp, mime-types, fileinfo

Have been trying to add some codes into the old written program, which i did not write because i have no idea how good this code might be working.
The following codes acts in two different pages with different forms.

```
$type = $this->data['Gallery']['type'];

if (!empty($this->data)) {
    if (!isset($this->data['Gallery']['gallery_category_id'])) {
        if ($this->data['Gallery']['type'] == 1) {
            echo "<script>alert('" . INFOGALLERYSECTION . "')</script>";
        } elseif ($this->data['Gallery']['type'] == 2) {
            echo "<script>alert('" . INFOSHROTSECTION . "')</script>";
        } else {
        }
    } else {
        // set the upload destination folder
        //$destination = realpath('../../app/webroot/img/gallery') . '/';

        $bigimg = WWW_ROOT . 'img/gallery/big/';
        $smallimg = WWW_ROOT . 'img/gallery/small/';

        // grab the file
        $file = $this->data['Gallery']['photofile'];
        $imageTypes = array("image/gif", "image/jpeg", "image/png"); //List of accepted file extensions. 
        foreach ($iamgeTypes as $type) {                 //check if image type fits one of allowed types
            if ($type == $this->data['type']) {
                // upload the image using the upload component
                $result = $this->Upload->upload($file, $bigimg, null, array('type' => 'resize', 'size' => '965', 'output' => 'jpg'));
                $result = $this->Upload->upload($file, $smallimg, null, array('type' => 'resize', 'size' => '146', 'output' => 'jpg'));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use cakephp validation

Comment: public $validate = array(
    'image' => array(
        'rule' => array(
            'extension',
            array('gif', 'jpeg', 'png', 'jpg')
        ),
        'message' => 'Please supply a valid image.'
    )
);

Answer (score 0):

You need to get mime type of uploaded file. There are two ways to do this depending on your PHP version.

**PHP 5.3 >=, PECL fileinfo >= 0.1.0**

```
$file = $this->data['Gallery']['photofile'];
$imageTypes = array("image/gif", "image/jpeg", "image/png"); //List of accepted file extensions.
// get file mime type
$fileInfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$fileType = finfo_file($fileInfo, $file);
finfo_close($fileInfo);

if (in_array($fileType, $imageTypes)) {
    $result = $this->Upload->upload($file, $bigimg, null, array('type' => 'resize', 'size' => '965', 'output' => 'jpg'));
    $result = $this->Upload->upload($file, $smallimg, null, array('type' => 'resize', 'size' => '146', 'output' => 'jpg'));
}
```

More about `fileinfo` functions you can find in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php).

**PHP 5.3 <**

```
// get file mime type
$fileType = mime_content_type($file);
```

[Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php) for `mime_content_type()` function.

I don't know how your model looks like, but it's good approach to move checking mime type in validator.

Comment: Thank you so much for going through it, so using mimi i don't have to use foreach to keep checking the extension of the uploaded file?

Comment: I changed `foreach` loop and `if` statement with `if` and [`in_array()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).

Comment: Its not working. Maybe there must be something wrong in the code itself.

Comment: Try to debug if image file reaches if statement.

Comment: it does not reach if condition

Comment: What is your PHP version? Is your code inside model?

Comment: 5.4.27 Php version. Yes I have a code in model. with out the foreach loop or if statement. its working fine but it does not check the files name

Comment: What do you mean by checking file name?

Comment: Its actually file extension, that we've been trying too add.. Sorry. 
Can i show you the code somewhere else ? there's little more coding beyond what I've posted

Comment: Its working now. I used 
    $ext = substr(strtolower(strrchr($file['name'], '.')), 1); 
insted of MIME

Comment: But it's not really safe. Someone can change e.g. executable script extension form .php to .gif and then he will be able to run whatever he want on your server.

Comment: I'll look forward to that, Thank you so much for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$file = $this->data["Gallery"]['photofile'];
if(!empty($file['tmp_name']))
{
    $type = explode('/', $file['type']);
    if($type[0] == 'image')
    {
     // Your Code
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey there. While this may be the answer to the question, it would be preferable to also explain why it will help. Try to explain to the OP what is the error, and how your solution works around it.